# Verify Android Internet Connection and Error

Tags: java, android, android-service

in a Service I'm using the following function for verifying internet connection:

```
 public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return !(networkInfo == null || !networkInfo.isConnected());
}
```

The problem is that if I have no Internet connection, I obtain the following in the Log:

```
 I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
 I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
 I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
```

So Android 5.1.1 are saying me that my application is slowing up my device and there are always error.

What's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Those messages seems to be caused by Samsung specific modifications to the ROMs. These may well be just debug messages sent to stdout.

Comment: The problem is that the UI of the smartphone is slowing while these errors occurs.

Comment: You can use an app such as OS Monitor to check which process is consuming your CPU.  If it is related to your call to isNetworkAvailable then you may try to check the status less often.

Answer (score 5):

Tis is the function that implements to check the Internet connection.

```
public boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    android.net.NetworkInfo networkinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkinfo != null && networkinfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's the same of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Trying following code snippet:

```
private boolean hasNetworkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    return isConnected;
}
```

Comment: getAllNetworkInfo() is deprecated. How to replace it?
Thanks.

Comment: It's the same of mine.

Comment: How about using BroadcastReceiver rather than Service?